# how to insert value from select list into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<select id='selectCat' name='selectCat'>
<option disabled selected value='0'>Select Type</option>
<option value='book'>Book</option>
<option value='txtbook'>Text Books</option>
<option value='notes'>Notes</option>
</select>
```

Above is the code in html.
I want the user to select one option from the select list and want to store that value into my database. But before storing it into database i am just retrieving the selected value as shown below.

```
$userCaT = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['selectCat']);
echo $userCat;
```

But it is showing an empty page.
So plz get me out from this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you connected to the database and stored any other values? What is the database name or table name that you are inserting into?

Comment: First of all check without mysqli_real_escape_string to find out if it's sent correctly.

Comment: Where is $userAdCat defined?

Comment: Might it be because you are fetching the variable into $userCaT, but showing the variable $userAdCat ?

Comment: Thanks Soraz for your great concern. Thanks alot